# ext. news set teaser text or long text required

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I do not manage to set the text fields in tx_news required.

If i try:

TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.teaser.config.eval = required

this doesn't work.
Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO this can't work currently as eval is not one of the fields which are overrideable. Those are defined in `FormEngineUtility` with

```
protected static $allowOverrideMatrix = [
    'input' => ['size', 'max', 'readOnly'],
    'text' => ['cols', 'rows', 'wrap', 'max', 'readOnly'],
    'check' => ['cols', 'readOnly'],
    'select' => ['size', 'autoSizeMax', 'maxitems', 'minitems', 'readOnly', 'treeConfig'],
    'group' => ['size', 'autoSizeMax', 'max_size', 'maxitems', 'minitems', 'readOnly'],
    'inline' => ['appearance', 'behaviour', 'foreign_label', 'foreign_selector', 'foreign_unique', 'maxitems', 'minitems', 'size', 'autoSizeMax', 'symmetric_label', 'readOnly'],
    'imageManipulation' => ['ratios', 'cropVariants']
];
```

---

Solutions are:

- Override it in TCA with a custom extension
- Create a custom formprovider and set it there